# Probability of event

Tags: probability, self-study

You average 3,000 customers per day, of which, on average, 54 are high net worth (HNW). If you have 200 sales associates, who average 15 interactions per day, what’s the probability that a sales associate would service a hnw customer on a given day? What’s the probability they would service a hnw client over the course of 6 days? 30 days?

Everything is random; associates all have an equal chance of working with a hnw client for every interaction; associates can only service one customer at a time. Solution should not include replacement - This assumption is what’s causing me confusion on how to solve.

I’m also not a student. This is a real business question I’m hoping to apply across numerous client types. This will enable me to show that the value of training client specific situations is not beneficial when 75% of our staff will only retain 25% of the training within 6 days if they have not applied it (per HBR).

I keep getting 126% per the image below

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: A simplified solution would assume replacement after counseling. Like pulling a ball out of an ern at random and replacing the ball after. So is likely a decent approximation given so many people and so few pretty balls. 

$P(HNW client|one draw)$   54/3000 = .018 
$P(HNW client|15 independent draws,w/, replacement)$   .018*15 = .27


A proper solution not assuming replacement would require a bit of combinatorics.

Comment: Thank you mindthedata, I appreciate your time. I apologize for the incorrect narrative as well. I’m struggling with extrapolating out the probability over time (x days) someone would have atleast 1 hnw client without replacement. I agree, this is a ‘picking probability’ type problem, I’m struggling to validate my answer however. That is, I know it’s not .27* x_days

Comment: Maybe you can break through your computational impasse by rethinking the question: given that you are averaging 54 HNW interactions per day, how can you *not* afford to train your sales associates?

Comment: Fair. But we have over 300 client types. Each with their own unique volume and training. With average training lasting 30 minutes costing about $6 a head. All said and done, we spend millions in capacity to do this. The intent of my calculation is to be able to apply the methodology more widely across our service model. That is, I care about more than just HNW.

Comment: That matters--potentially a lot.  Might I suggest, then, that you modify your post to include the full context and to ask the question you really need answered?